# How to set a filter for a DataGrid ItemSource via MVVM

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have a *DataGrid* bound to a *CollectionViewSource* in XAML.

```
<Window.Resources>
  <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsEntries" 
                        Source="{Binding LogEntriesStore, 
                                 Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

`LogEntriesStore` is an *ObservableCollection*  (*LogEntry* is a DTO that's not important in this discussion)

The *DataGrid* is declared as:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          Margin="0" 
          Name="dataGrid1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsEntries}}" 
          IsReadOnly="True">
```

Now I have context menus on various cells in this *DataGrid*, to kick off a request for filtering.  Right click on a cell, and pick filter to filter all the rows, and show only this particular value.

The MVVM gets the request to filter, but the now the tricky bit.  How do I set the filter on the CollectionViewSource?

(as an aside -- this would have been a walk in the park with a Silverlight `PagedCollectionView` but that doesn't seem to be available in WPF, is that right?)

Comment: is this what you are looking for http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=31

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Very simple. You just need to move the collection view inside the view model:

1. In `MainWindowViewModel` define a property of type `ICollectionView`:

   ```
   public ICollectionView LogEntriesStoreView { get; private set; }
   ```
2. Right after you have initialized the `LogEntriesStore` property, you need to initialize the `LogEntriesStoreView` property with the following code:

   ```
   LogEntriesStoreView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(LogEntriesStore);
   ```
3. Then you need to remove the `CollectionViewSource` from XAML and modify the `ItemsSource` binding to point to the newly created collection view property:

   ```
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
             Margin="0" 
             Name="dataGrid1" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntriesStoreView, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" 
             IsReadOnly="True">
   ```

That's it. Now you have the access to the collection view inside your view model, where you can modify the filter.

Comment: The problem with that approach that ICollectionView is readonly, ergo you are going to be blocked for add/remove rows by default. Therefore I recommend using ListCollectionView instead.

Comment: In .net standard, ICollectionView is no more available.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to your problem, but in my opinion, the best solutions are the ones which uses only styles with the standard WPF `DataGrid` control without inventing a new inherited `DataGird` type or depending on another third-party control. The followings are the best solutions I found:

- Option 1: which I personally use: [Automatic WPF Toolkit DataGrid Filtering](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DataGridFilterLibrary.aspx)
- Option 2:  [Auto-filter for Microsoft WPF DataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpffiltering.aspx)