# search on data grid wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

i already bind all the data into my data grid. 
Now i want to perform a search.

i figured it out, i can do sql connection to search. but i only want to do search on my datagrid. because my data already bind to my datagrid.

here is the pic
[image]

at the top, i have a textbox. how can i do a search / filtering by using the textbox?
maybe i could type 'Bahan Baku', it will search on 'Nama Kategori'. or i also can type 'Sayur', it will search on 'Keterangan Kategori'. and what i type, will affect on my datagrid.

any advice? thanks.

**EDIT**

Here is my code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //private ICollectionView MyData;
    //string SearchText = string.Empty;
    ObservableCollection<Category> _data = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
    public ObservableCollection<Category> data { get { return _data; } }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        showData();
    }

    private void showData()
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = null;
        OleDbCommand cmd = null;

        try
        {
            conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=dbDemo1.accdb");
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("select categoryID, categoryDesc, categoryItem from t_category", conn);
            conn.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    data.Add(new Category
                        {
                            nCateogryID = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString()),
                            sCategoryDesc = reader[1].ToString(),
                            sCategoryItems = reader[2].ToString()
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
            SearchText = t.Text.ToString();
            MyData.Filter = FilterData;
        }

    private bool FilterData(object item)
    {
        var value = (Category)item;
        if (value == null || value.nCateogryID == null)
            return false;
        return value.sCategoryDesc.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower()) || value.sCategoryItems.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower());
        //return value.Book_Id.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower()) || value.Book_Name.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower()) || value.Author_Name.ToLower().ToString().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower()) || value.Publisher_Name.ToLower().ToString().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower().ToString()) || value.Book_Genre.ToLower().ToString().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower().ToString()) || value.Language.ToLower().ToString().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower().ToString()) || value.Book_EntryDate.ToLower().ToString().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower().ToString());
    }
}
```

this is my class category looks like:

```
public class Category
{
    public int nCateogryID { get; set; } 
    public int nCategoryMaster { get; set; }
    public int nCategoryDetail { get; set; }

    public string sCategoryDesc { get; set; }
    public string sCategoryItems { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SearchGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="258" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,12" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="479">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ncategoryID}" Header="No." IsReadOnly="True" Width="30" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding sCategoryDesc}" Header="Nama Kategori" IsReadOnly="True" Width="160" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding sCategoryItems}" Header="Keterangan Kategori" IsReadOnly="True" Width="247" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I got this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add TextChanged Event in xaml like

```
<TextBox Text="" Width="115" Canvas.Left="210" Canvas.Top="37" Height="23" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
```

in your cs file Your TextChanged event look like

```
 private ICollectionView MyData;
    string SearchText=string.Empty;
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
          TextBox t= sender as TextBox;
          SearchText=t.Text.ToString();
          MyData.Filter = FilterData;
        }
    private bool FilterData(object item)
        {
        var value = (Book_Information)item;
        if (value == null || value.Book_Id == null)
            return false;
        return value.Book_Id.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower()) || value.Book_Name.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower()) || value.Author_Name.ToLower().ToString().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower()) || value.Publisher_Name.ToLower().ToString().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower().ToString()) || value.Book_Genre.ToLower().ToString().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower().ToString()) || value.Language.ToLower().ToString().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower().ToString()) || value.Book_EntryDate.ToLower().ToString().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower().ToString());
        }
```

MyData Contains your Whole Collection of Data 
here is example

```
ViewBook=new ObservableCollection<Book_Information>();
dataGrid1.ItemsSource=ViewBook;
MyData=CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ViewBook);
```

Comment: hi.. i already can implement your code.. i can use it.. thanks btw.. :) but how can i bind selecteditem from my datagrid to textbox? any idea?

Comment: means you want to bind one selecteditem from datagrid to textbox or one item from selecteditem?

Comment: You Can use                                            Return_IssueBook book = new Return_IssueBook();                   book = (Return_IssueBook)datagrid1.CurrentCell.Item;

Comment: thanks.. i done it.. but i binding into the xaml.. thanks for your advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the dataGrid by binding it to `ICollectionView` which provides support of filtering on source collection. Details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126.aspx) and this might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809895/how-to-set-a-filter-for-a-datagrid-itemsource-via-mvvm) you too.

Comment: do you have any example of that one? because its to complicated. thanks.